# Windows Form is setting the data row state to detached. How can I preserve the data row state as well as it's data?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I am storing data in a data row to perform operations on the data later. I have a confirm dialog box which is used for confirmation of the operation to be performed on the data.

`showDialog` is called to display the confirmation dialog box with Ok, Cancel buttons, regardless of the selection of buttons, the row state of the data row is becoming detached and Item Array is throwing an exception

> System.Data.DataException {System.Data.RowNotInTableException.

**Code:**

```
//DataRow dataTobeHold = dataSource[0](Another datarow fetched from database)
DataRow dataHold =new DataRow();
dataHold= dataTobeHold;
Form prompt = new Form();
DialogResult result=prompt.ShowDialog();
//Before reaching if, the dataHold's row state is detached.
if(result==DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    cancelFunction();
}
```

Note: Row state is becoming detached even before the execution Ok/Cancel functions. Even closing the dialog box is making the row state detached.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: It IS detached. Where's the table you want it to belong to?

Comment: The general way to make a new row that belongs to a table is to use something like dtList1 = new DataTable(); DataRow newrow = dtList1.NewRow(); dtList1.Rows.Add(newrow);

Comment: Can't we just use Data Row ? Why do we have to create Data Table?

Comment: @Nani2015 When you create `DataRow`, it is by default in `Detached` state and it is normal. The code doesn't show us where do you receive the exception.

Comment: It's better to share a simple code to reproduce the error. The first benefit of writing such code is you usually can detect and solve the problem yourself. Then if you couldn't find the problem we can use the code to reproduce the error and help you to solve the problem.

Comment: I have used message Box instead of Form and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used message Box instead of Form and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What is your DataSource? Is it the full code? please show us the full code.
However, As I remember from C#, when you want to get a value from DataRow, you should do it like that:

```
DataRow dataTobeHold=new DataRow(); //creates DataRow
dataTobeHold = dataSource[0]; //Gets the first row from the dataSource
```

Again, please attach the full code for more helpfull answers.

Comment: Using `new` in this code is redundant.  You are creating a new instance of a `DataRow` and then just throwing that instance away.  Instead just use  `DataRow dataTobeHold = datasource[0];`